# Docker-Compose with Commandbox cannot change web root

Tags: docker, docker-compose, coldfusion, cfml, lucee

I'm using `docker-compose` to launch a commandbox lucee container and a mysql contianer.

I'd like to change the web root of the lucee server, to keep all my non-public files hidden (server.json etc, cfmigrations resources folder)

I've followed the docs and updated my `server.json`
https://commandbox.ortusbooks.com/embedded-server/server.json/packaging-your-server

```
{
    "web":{
        "webroot":"./public"
    }
}
```

If I launch the server from Windows (`box start` from the app folder), the server loads my index.cfm from `./public` at http://localhost, perfect.

But using this `.yaml` file, the webroot doesn't change to `./public` and the contents of my `/app` folder is shown, with the "public" folder visible in the directory listing.

```
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.26
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
      MYSQL_DATABASE: cf
      MYSQL_USER: $MYSQL_USER
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_PASSWORD
      MYSQL_SOURCE: $MYSQL_SOURCE
      MYSQL_SOURCE_USER: $MYSQL_SOURCE_USER
      MYSQL_SOURCE_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_SOURCE_PASSWORD
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./assets/initdb:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./assets/sql:/assets/sql

  web:
    depends_on:
      - db
    # Post 3.1.0 fails to boot if APP_DIR is set to non /app
    # image: ortussolutions/commandbox:lucee5-3.1.0
    image: ortussolutions/commandbox:lucee5
    # build: .
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    environment:
        - PORT=80
        - SSL_PORT=443
        - BOX_SERVER_WEB_SSL_ENABLE=true
        - BOX_SERVER_WEB_DIRECTORYBROWSING=$CF_DIRECTORY_BROWSING
        - BOX_INSTALL=true
        - BOX_SERVER_WEB_BLOCKCFADMIN=$CF_BLOCK_ADMIN
        - BOX_SERVER_CFCONFIGFILE=/app/.cfconfig.json 
        
        # - APP_DIR=/app/public
        # - BOX_SERVER_WEB_WEBROOT=/app/public
        
        - cfconfig_robustExceptionEnabled=$CF_ROBOUST_EXCEPTION_ENABLED
        - cfconfig_adminPassword=$CF_ADMIN_PASSWORD

        - MYSQL_USER=$MYSQL_USER
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_PASSWORD
        - MYSQL_HOST=$MYSQL_HOST
        - MYSQL_PORT=$MYSQL_PORT
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
      - ./assets/mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar:/usr/local/lib/CommandBox/lib/mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar
```

Here's the directory listing:

[image: directory listing of /app folder]

This is my project structure:

[image: project structure]

It seems like the `server.json` file is being ignored or at least the `web.webroot` property, but I've tried both of these settings, and neither solve the problem

```
- APP_DIR=/app/public
- BOX_SERVER_WEB_WEBROOT=/app/public
```

The commandbox docs suggest changing APP_DIR to fix the web root, "APP_DIR - Application directory (web root)."
https://hub.docker.com/r/ortussolutions/commandbox/

But if I do that, I get an error about the startup script being in the wrong place, which to me looks like it should be fixed:
https://github.com/Ortus-Solutions/docker-commandbox/issues/55

The `BOX_SERVER_WEB_WEBROOT` is in the same way `server.json` is (or at least that property). I've tried setting the following env vars as well (both upper and lower case) and it makes no diffence, but bear in mind `server.json` changes the webroot for me whe

- BOX_SERVER_WEB_WEBROOT=./public
- BOX_SERVER_WEB_WEBROOT=/app/public
- BOX_SERVER_WEB_WEBROOT=public

The output as the web container starts up:

```
Set verboseErrors = true

INFO: CF Engine defined as lucee@5.3.8+189

INFO: Convention .cfconfig.json found at /app/.cfconfig.json

INFO: Server Home Directory set to: /usr/local/lib/serverHome

 √ | Installing ALL dependencies

   | √ | Installing package [forgebox:commandbox-cfconfig@1.6.3]

   | √ | Installing package [forgebox:commandbox-migrations@3.2.3]

   |   | √ | Installing package [forgebox:cfmigrations@^2.0.0]

   |   |   | √ | Installing package [forgebox:qb@^8.0.0]

   |   |   |   | √ | Installing package [forgebox:cbpaginator@^2.4.0]

+ [[ -n '' ]]

+ [[ -n '' ]]

INFO: Generating server startup script

 √ | Starting Server

   |------------------------------

   | start server in - /app/

   | server name - app

   | server config file - /app//server.json

   | WAR/zip archive already installed.

   | Found CFConfig JSON in ".cfconfig.json" file in web root by convention

   | .

   | Importing luceeserver config from [/app/.cfconfig.json]

   | Config transferred!

   | Setting OS environment variable [cfconfig_adminPassword] into luceeser

   | ver

   | [adminPassword] set.

   | Setting OS environment variable [cfconfig_robustExceptionEnabled] into

   |  luceeserver

   | [robustExceptionEnabled] set.

   | Start script for shell [bash] generated at: /app/server-start.sh

   | Server start command: 

   |     /opt/java/openjdk/bin/java 

   |     -jar /usr/local/lib/CommandBox/lib/runwar-4.5.1.jar 

   |     --background=false 

   |     --host 0.0.0.0 

   |     --stop-port 42777 

   |     --processname app [lucee 5.3.8+189] 

   |     --log-dir /usr/local/lib/serverHome//logs 

   |     --server-name app 

   |     --tray-enable false 

   |     --dock-enable true 

   |     --directoryindex true 

   |     --timeout 240 

   |     --proxy-peeraddress true 

   |     --cookie-secure false 

   |     --cookie-httponly false 

   |     --pid-file /usr/local/lib/serverHome//.pid.txt 

   |     --gzip-enable true 

   |     --cfengine-name lucee 

   |     -war /app/ 

   |     --web-xml-path /usr/local/lib/serverHome/WEB-INF/web.xml 

   |     --http-enable true 

   |     --ssl-enable true 

   |     --ajp-enable false 

   |     --http2-enable true 

   |     --open-browser false 

   |     --open-url https://0.0.0.0:443 

   |     --port 80 

   |     --ssl-port 443 

   |     --urlrewrite-enable false 

   |     --predicate-file /usr/local/lib/serverHome//.predicateFile.txt

   | Dry run specified, exiting without starting server.

   |------------------------------

   | √ | Setting Server Profile to [production]

   |   |-----------------------------------------------------

   |   | Profile set from secure by default

   |   | Block CF Admin disabled

   |   | Block Sensitive Paths enabled

   |   | Block Flash Remoting enabled

   |   | Directory Browsing enabled

   |   |-----------------------------------------------------

INFO: Starting server using generated script: /usr/local/bin/startup.sh

[INFO ] runwar.server: Starting RunWAR 4.5.1

[INFO ] runwar.server: HTTP2 Enabled:true

[INFO ] runwar.server: Enabling SSL protocol on port 443

[INFO ] runwar.server: HTTP ajpEnable:false

[INFO ] runwar.server: HTTP warFile exists:true

[INFO ] runwar.server: HTTP warFile isDirectory:true

[INFO ] runwar.server: HTTP background:false

[INFO ] runwar.server: Adding additional lib dir of: /usr/local/lib/serverHome/WEB-INF/lib

[INFO ] runwar.server: ******************************************************************************

[INFO ] runwar.server: Starting - port:80 stop-port:42777 warpath:file:/app/

[INFO ] runwar.server: context: /  -  version: 4.5.1

[INFO ] runwar.server: web-dirs: ["\/app"]

[INFO ] runwar.server: Log Directory: /usr/local/lib/serverHome/logs

[INFO ] runwar.server: ******************************************************************************

[INFO ] runwar.server: XNIO-Option CONNECTION_LOW_WATER:1000000

[INFO ] runwar.server: XNIO-Option CORK:true

[INFO ] runwar.server: XNIO-Option WORKER_TASK_MAX_THREADS:30

[INFO ] runwar.server: XNIO-Option WORKER_IO_THREADS:8

[INFO ] runwar.server: XNIO-Option TCP_NODELAY:true

[INFO ] runwar.server: XNIO-Option WORKER_TASK_CORE_THREADS:30

[INFO ] runwar.server: XNIO-Option CONNECTION_HIGH_WATER:1000000

[INFO ] runwar.config: Parsing '/usr/local/lib/serverHome/WEB-INF/web.xml'

[INFO ] runwar.server: Extensions allowed by the default servlet for static files: 3gp,3gpp,7z,ai,aif,aiff,asf,asx,atom,au,avi,bin,bmp,btm,cco,crt,css,csv,deb,der,dmg,doc,docx,eot,eps,flv,font,gif,hqx,htc,htm,html,ico,img,ini,iso,jad,jng,jnlp,jpeg,jpg,js,json,kar,kml,kmz,m3u8,m4a,m4v,map,mid,midi,mml,mng,mov,mp3,mp4,mpeg,mpeg4,mpg,msi,msm,msp,ogg,otf,pdb,pdf,pem,pl,pm,png,ppt,pptx,prc,ps,psd,ra,rar,rpm,rss,rtf,run,sea,shtml,sit,svg,svgz,swf,tar,tcl,tif,tiff,tk,ts,ttf,txt,wav,wbmp,webm,webp,wmf,wml,wmlc,wmv,woff,woff2,xhtml,xls,xlsx,xml,xpi,xspf,zip,aifc,aac,apk,bak,bk,bz2,cdr,cmx,dat,dtd,eml,fla,gz,gzip,ipa,ia,indd,hey,lz,maf,markdown,md,mkv,mp1,mp2,mpe,odt,ott,odg,odf,ots,pps,pot,pmd,pub,raw,sdd,tsv,xcf,yml,yaml

[INFO ] runwar.server: welcome pages in deployment manager: [index.cfm, index.lucee, index.html, index.htm]

WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred

WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.felix.framework.ext.ClassPathExtenderFactory$DefaultClassLoaderExtender (file:/usr/local/lib/serverHome/WEB-INF/lib/lucee.jar) to method java.net.URLClassLoader.addURL(java.net.URL)

WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.felix.framework.ext.ClassPathExtenderFactory$DefaultClassLoaderExtender

WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations

WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

[INFO ] runwar.server: Direct Buffers: true

[INFO ] runwar.server: ******************************************************************************

[INFO ] runwar.server: *** starting 'stop' listener thread - Host: 0.0.0.0 - Socket: 42777

[INFO ] runwar.server: ******************************************************************************

[INFO ] runwar.server: Server is up - http-port:80 https-port:443 stop-port:42777 PID:286 version 4.5.1
```

This is all fairly new to me so I might have done something completely wrong, I'm wondering if it's a problem with the folder nesting, although I've tried rearranging it and can't come up with a working solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a pre-warmed image

```
image: ortussolutions/commandbox:lucee5
```

That means the server has already been started and "locked in" to all its settings, including the web root.  Use the vanilla commandbox image that has never had a server started, that way when you warm up the image, you'll be starting it with your settings the first time.

To set a custom web root, you'll want to add this to your docker file

```
ENV APP_DIR=/app/public
```

Comment: How do I do that, omit the `:lucee5`?

Comment: aaaah I see in the docs now, " Containers with warmed-up engines", I'll take that out then and specify the engine in `server.json`

Comment: not using a pre-warmed image has sorted it, the webroot is being read from the `server.json`